# UWP listview virtualisation issue with a combobox in the listview item

Tags: uwp

We are building functionality in a large enterprise solution. One of the pages constists of a listview with over 50 items in it. When the user fills in the top few items and scrolls down and up, the data of a number of these filled-in comboboxes are cleared.

This happens both when SelectedItem or SelectedIndex are being used.

To narrow down the problem, I have built a small sample application which contains just a very basic page with listview to reproduce the problem. This way I know the problem is not the business logic, but in the core UWP layer.

This application has been tested in VS2019 and VS2022, also on a couple of Windows 10 and 11 versions. The issue was reported in all environments.

The git repository is available at https://bitbucket.org/overmeijerm/uwp-virtualisation-issue/src/master/.

Answer (score 0):

You use [data virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization), UWP will reuse your items when scrolling down and up, and the result is that your data will lost.

If you want to save user-selected data, **you need to disable data virtualization**.
You can add a `stackPanel` in `<ListView.ItemsPanel>` to disable it.

The following is a code sample, hope it will help you.

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="List" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
       
        <ListView.GroupStyle >
            <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}" />
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I could disable virtualisation, but is this as-designed? Why introduce virtualisation while it cannot keep the entered data? Or is virtualisation not designed to be used when the control is being used for user input?

Comment: This behavior is caused by data virtualization. Similarly, textBlock will have duplicate content during scrolling, selected items will be lost.